# XMLBeans project is not avaialble to request a Jira account

Tags: xml, jira, xmlbeans

I need to request a Jira account to submit a ticket for XMLBeans, but I cannot find the project name XMLBEANS on the form.

Existing tickets are included in the XMLBEANS project
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/XMLBEANS/issues/XMLBEANS-426?filter=allopenissues

[image]

But, on the request form, I cannot see the XMLBEANS project from the select box control https://selfserve.apache.org/jira-account.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

XMLBeans is maintained by the Apache POI team. Request a JIRA account for the POI project instead. In the reason field, mention XMLBeans. The main POI bug tracker is https://bz.apache.org/. You can use this too.